# execute script with C++

Tags: c++, c, linux, boinc

I want to execute a script through a c++ program and get its output. Presently I am doing

```
system("./script.sh > out.txt");
```

But I need a command that get the output to a string, some thing like:

```
out = system("./script.sh");
printf(out);
```

I can't read the file out.txt after execute the script because I don't have permission to that. I deployed my c++ program at other framework (boinc) that doesn't give me this permission.

Does anybody have a hint?
Thanks in advance!
Felipe

Comment: Change the file permission with `chmod` in the system routine?

Comment: Seems like you want the [`popen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) function?

Comment: duplicate. Please look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-to-execute-a-command-and-get-output-of-command-within-c/478960#478960

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `popen()` and then get the output of the command from the pipe opened by `popen()`

```
FILE  *fp;
fp=popen("./script.sh","r");
```

and to get your output. you can use `fgets()` or `fread()` to read from pipe like you read from a file